# How to display a view in Joomla controller?

Tags: joomla

I have a script that uploads to a folder and I want to display a view after the upload is done, successful or not.

```
/component
  /admin/
    /views/
      /components/
        view.html.php
        /tmpl/
          default.php
          modal.php // I want to load and output this file from controller.php
    component.php
    controller.php
 /site/
```

I would like to do something like this, in my controller

```
 $view = $this->getView(/* params for modal.php to load*/); //get the view
 $this->view->display();
```

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
$view = $this->getView( 'components', 'html' );
$view->setLayout('modal');
$view->display();
```

or

```
JRequest::setVar('view', 'components');
JRequest::setVar('layout', 'modal');
```